# Jumping down anchors (in a table)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Seems to works sometimes, and other times it doesn't. It's incredibly rough and horrible to use.

simplified layout:

```js
var index = 1
function next() {
  if (index <= 4){
    window.location.replace('#r' + index.toString());
    index++;
  }
}
function previous() {
  if (index > 1){
    index--;
    window.location.replace('#r' + index.toString());
  }
}
```

```css
.what {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick='next()' id="nxt">Next</a>
<a href="#" onclick='previous()' id="prev">Previous</a>

<body>
<table>
  <tr class="what">
    <td id="r1">r</td>
    <td>o</td>
    <td>w</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="what">
    <td id="r2">r</td>
    <td>o</td>
    <td>w</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="what">
    <td id="r3">r</td>
    <td>o</td>
    <td>w</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="what">
    <td id="r4">r</td>
    <td>o</td>
    <td>w</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

For some reason, it seems to only work for id#r1 and id#r4. Is there a better, smoother way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links are still doing what they normally do. This means there will be interference between trying to set location to `#r1` and the link trying to set location to `#`.

Instead, setup the event handlers through javascript and use `preventDefault()` to stop the links from doing their default action.

I took the liberty of correct some other, minor bugs as well.

```js
var index = 0
function next(event) {
  if (index < 4){
    index++;
    window.location.replace('#r' + index.toString());
  }
  event.preventDefault();
}
function previous(event) {
  if (index > 1){
    index--;
    window.location.replace('#r' + index.toString());
  }
  event.preventDefault();
}
document
  .getElementById('nxt')
  .addEventListener( 'click', next );
document
  .getElementById('prev')
  .addEventListener( 'click', previous );
```

```css
table {
  width:100%;
}
.what {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="nxt">Next</a>
<a href="#" id="prev">Previous</a>

<body>
<table>
  <tr class="what">
    <td id="r1">r</td>
    <td>o</td>
    <td>w</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="what">
    <td id="r2">r</td>
    <td>o</td>
    <td>w</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="what">
    <td id="r3">r</td>
    <td>o</td>
    <td>w</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="what">
    <td id="r4">r</td>
    <td>o</td>
    <td>w</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! I didn't even realize it was the link overriding my function.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var index = 1
function next() {
  if (index < 4){
  index++;
    window.location.hash=('#r' + index.toString());
    console.log('next',window.location.hash)
  }
}
function previous() {
  if (index > 1){
    index--;
    window.location.hash=('#r' + index.toString());
    console.log('prev',window.location.hash)
  }
}
```

```css
.what {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick='next()' id="nxt">Next</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)"onclick='previous()' id="prev">Previous</a>

<body>
<table>
  <tr class="what">
    <td id="r1">r</td>
    <td>o</td>
    <td>w</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="what">
    <td id="r2">r</td>
    <td>o</td>
    <td>w</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="what">
    <td id="r3">r</td>
    <td>o</td>
    <td>w</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="what">
    <td id="r4">r</td>
    <td>o</td>
    <td>w</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```